# Include the date that are not in the `BETWEEN` range in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

Is it possible to include the date that are not in the `BETWEEN` range?

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'

+--------+------------+
|  User  |    Date    |
+--------+------------+
| John   | 2018-06-21 |
| Mike   | 2018-05-16 |
| Jessie | 0000-00-00 | <!-- include this as well -->
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: try where (date between from and to) or (date = '0000-00-00')

Comment: Thankyou! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice would be Union, if you want to include dates from specific users.

```
(SELECT * from tableName 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59')
UNION 
(SELECT * from tableName where `User` like 'Jessie');
```

If you just want to add additional dates you can use OR.

```
SELECT * from tableName 
WHERE date BETWEEN ('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59')
OR
date IN (date1, date2, date3)
```